# Why are my Excel sheets being cleared? Using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am doing a fairly simple Excel I/O from several input sheets to one master sheet. The output is to be printed to one master sheet, in a book containing several other sheets. For some reason, while the input and printing is happening without any issues, the non-text (charts and images) of the other sheets in the book are being cleared. This is not what is intended, I just wanted to print the data directly into the sheet and leave everything else as it is. 
At the top:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import *
```

This is the code that I'm using to open the output workbook.

```
#locate and open the master book and sheet
master_sheet_location = os.path.join(directory,master_sheet)
wb = load_workbook(master_sheet_location)
sheets = wb.sheetnames
Sheet1 = wb[sheets[1]]
```

After printing the data, I save it with the following line of code:

```
wb.save(master_sheet_location)
```

The data are then read and printed iteratively to Sheet1. Is there something I'm not doing to preserve the rest of the sheets? I'm not dealing with the other sheets at all in the code.

Comment: I found this warning in the [docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html): *openpyxl does currently not read all possible items in an Excel file so images and charts will be lost from existing files __if they are opened and saved with the same name__.* Also, don't `import *`. The idiomatic way to work with `openpyxl` is doing `from openpyxl import load_workbook` (or `Workbook` depending on if you want to open or create a workbook)

Comment: @Tomerikoo oh I see, so openpyxl can only be used for text? Any ideas about how to output to an existing sheet? My understanding is that xlwt cannot be used to print to an existing sheet, while openpyxl can, but I did not realize the limitation of no images or charts..Thanks for the tips.

Comment: I only use `openpyxl` for basic usage for parsing text excels, I just found that warning trying to look for some solution. Regarding the `xlwt`, the usual way of doing that is using `xlrd` to read the excel, then using `xlwt.copy` (not sure of the exact way) to create a writeable copy and that might work. Lastly, you might try `xlwings`. I don't have any personal experience with it but I think it might be better suited for those kind of stuff. Hope that helps in any way

Comment: @Tomerikoo thank you!